# Plotting two time based data values on a single chart in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two worksheets which look like this:
[Worksheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpUYy.jpg)
and
[Worksheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg2vI.jpg).
As you can see both of these data sets have a time column and the other are the columns which I want to plot respective to time (time on x-axis and values on y-axis). The data points in the first set are equally spaced (in time) and are less in number whereas the data points in the second set are spaced unequally and are more in number. Is there a way to plot both of the value columns ('Value of A' and 'Value of 1') on a single time axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do this.  You can add the "Value of A" data to a graph of the "Value of 1" data.

Here is the process:

1. Select all of the times and values of the "Value of 1" data, and
   plot it by choosing one of the XY Scatter options from the Insert
   tab.
2. Select the chart by clicking on it and choose Source Data... from
   the Chart menu.
3. Click the "Add" button, and in the resulting dialog box, specify the
   ranges for the X-values and Y-values of the "Value of A" data.
4. Click "OK", and the "Value of A" data will be added to the graph.

The resulting graph will have all the values plotted on the same time axis, and the two data series will be distinguished by the color and type of data marker.  You can format the markers to look the same if you wish.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please click on the grey check mark at the top left to accept it and remove it from the unanswered queue.